# how to compare list of value and add info

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have start a code to create and compare 2 list, and now, I'am getting stuck for going to the next step.
I would like to do this :

1- create list 01 and list 02

2- compare list

3- When I found a word from the list 02 into the list 01

I want to copy the info from the colmun 1/3/4/20/21/22/23 from row of the word from the list 01

and then copy it into the column 1/3/4/28/29/30/31 from the row of the word in list 02

here is the code I start :

```
function REA_PROJET_002() {

  //Sheet
  var REA_PROJsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TEST_PROJETS");
  var INFO_PROJsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("INFOS_PROJETS");
  var PROsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_LISTE PROJETS");
  
  //list 01
  var projnamePRO = PROsheet.getRange(5, 2, PROsheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  //list 02
  var projnameCO = REA_PROJsheet.getRange(2, 2, REA_PROJsheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  Logger.log((projnameCO))
  
var listePRO = projnamePRO.map((r, i) => {
    let idx = projnameCO.indexOf(r[1])
    if(!~idx) {
       Logger.log('OK');

    }
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this script, it will go through both list and copy the values as needed using the row from each iteration:

```
function REA_PROJET_002() {

  //Sheet
  var REA_PROJsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TEST_PROJETS");
  var INFO_PROJsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("INFOS_PROJETS");
  var PROsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_LISTE PROJETS");

  //list 01
  var projnamePRO = PROsheet.getRange(5, 2, PROsheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  //list 02
  var projnameCO = REA_PROJsheet.getRange(2, 2, REA_PROJsheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  var list01Columns = [1, 3, 4, 20, 21, 22, 23];
  var list02Columns = [1, 3, 4, 28, 29, 30, 31];

  for (i = 0; i < projnameCO.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < projnamePRO.length; j++) {
      if (projnameCO[i][0] == projnamePRO[j][0] && projnameCO[i][0] !== "") {

        for (k = 0; k < list01Columns.length; k++) {
          console.log(k);
          REA_PROJsheet.getRange(i + 2, list02Columns[k]).setValue(
            PROsheet.getRange(j + 5, list01Columns[k]).getValue()
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example:

[image]

---

Please share a set of sample data showing its initial state and desired output if this doesn't fit what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your situation, I think that `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` can be declared at one time.
- In the case of `PROsheet.getRange(5, 2, PROsheet.getLastRow()).getValues()` and `REA_PROJsheet.getRange(2, 2, REA_PROJsheet.getLastRow()).getValues()`, more 4 rows from the last row are retrieved.
- From `copy the info from the colmun 1/3/4/20/21/22/23` of your question, if the values of `1/3/4/20/21/22/23` are the column number, it seems that it is required to retrieve the values from column "A". It supposes that `1` is column "A" in your situation.
- In your script, `projnamePRO` is an array like `[["a2"],["a3"],,,]`. So, `r[1]` in the loop is always undefined. By this, `Logger.log('OK')` is shown in every loop. The initial number of the array is 0. Please be careful about this.
- `INFO_PROJsheet` is not used.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please confirm your sheet names again. And save the script.

```js
function REA_PROJET_002() {
  // Retrieve source and destination sheets.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var list01Sheet = ss.getSheetByName("0_LISTE PROJETS");
  var list02Sheet = ss.getSheetByName("TEST_PROJETS");

  // Retrieve values from source and destination sheets.
  var list01 = list01Sheet.getRange(5, 1, list01Sheet.getLastRow() - 4, list01Sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dstRange = list02Sheet.getRange(2, 1, list02Sheet.getLastRow() - 1, list02Sheet.getLastColumn());
  var list02 = dstRange.getValues();

  // Create destination values.
  var srcColumnNumbers = [1, 3, 4, 20, 21, 22, 23];
  var dstColumnNumbers = [1, 3, 4, 28, 29, 30, 31];
  var obj = list01.reduce((o, r) => (o[r[1]] = srcColumnNumbers.map(i => r[i - 1] || null), o), {});
  var dstValues = list02.map(r => {
    if (obj[r[1]]) {
      dstColumnNumbers.forEach((e, i) => r[e - 1] = obj[r[1]][i] || null);
    }
    return r;
  });

  // Update destination sheet by new values.
  dstRange.setValues(dstValues);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from "0_LISTE PROJETS" (list01) and "TEST_PROJETS" (list02). And, the search the values from column "B" of list01 using the values of column "B" of list02. When the value of column "B" of list02 is found in the value of column "B" of list01, the values of `srcColumnNumbers` of list01 is copied to `dstColumnNumbers` of list02. And, the destination sheet is updated.
- In this modification, it supposes that `var srcColumnNumbers = [1, 3, 4, 20, 21, 22, 23];` and `var dstColumnNumbers = [1, 3, 4, 28, 29, 30, 31];` are the column number (the 1st number is 1 (column "A")). Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: hey !thank you very much, your code look pretty cool, but the code don't seems to works. The logger tel me this : `ReferenceError: srcColumnNumbers is not defined` and then if I change `srcColumnNumber` for `list01` that I guess should be the good things to do, it stop with this message : `ReferenceError: dstColumnNumbers is not defined`... and I don't know what to do !

Comment: @antho2B Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `ReferenceError: srcColumnNumbers is not defined`, when I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. And also, about `ReferenceError: dstColumnNumbers is not defined`, unfortunately, in my script, you can see that `srcColumnNumbers` and `dstColumnNumbers` are declared. From this situation, I'm worried that you might not correctly use my proposed script.

Comment: @antho2B But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script using my proposed script? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your current issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: thanks for your help ! You were right ! I have made a mistake while copying and editing your code. I'am fill so sorry about it ! But what ever, the code is till nont running. I will take a bit of time later to update with an online example !

Comment: @antho2B Thank you for replying. About `I have made a mistake while copying and editing your code.`, I understood it. About `But what ever, the code is till nont running.`, in this case, it is required to confirm your Spreadsheet using my proposed script. Because, when I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. I apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script using my proposed script? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your current issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @antho2B If you can cooperate to resolve your current issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?